# I cannot get my api call from google-translate to work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api, google-translate

I cannot figure out how to display the word that I am translating with my google-translate API ... I want to display the translated word from function newText to get displayed in the Text tag where I call that function.. (also the word to translate it's coming from the TextInput 'word to translate'

```
const Main = ({ navigation }) => {
  let apiKey = "AIzaasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfsdc";
  let googleTranslate = require("google-translate")(apiKey);

  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  const newText = () => {
    googleTranslate.translate(text, "es", function (err, translation) {
      return translation.translatedText;
    });
  };

  const onChangeText = (text) => setText(text);
  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <ImageBackground
        source={require("./assets/book.png")}
        style={styles.backgroundImage}
      >
        <View style={styles.innerText}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>Welcome back Elisa, </Text>
          <Text>let's practice that pronunciation...</Text>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Word to translate"
            style={styles.input}
            onChangeText={onChangeText}
          />
        </View>

        <Text style={styles.output}>{newText()}</Text>

        <View style={styles.button}>
          <Button
            title="START"
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("BACK_HOME")}
          />
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I've converted newText() into an async function.

You can either call newText() with a onClick event, or use onChange as I've modified your codes below.

Google translate will be called whenever your input change (it's not a good idea because it means if you type 100 characters, it translate 100 times.).

I suggest you to add a button like this.

`<button onClick={() => newText(text)}>Translate Me!</button>`

```
const Main = ({ navigation }) => {
  let apiKey = "AIzaasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfsdc";
  let googleTranslate = require("google-translate")(apiKey);

  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [ translated, setTranslated ] = useState('');

  const newText = async (toBeTranslated) => {
    await googleTranslate.translate(toBeTranslated, "es", function (err, translation) {
      setTranslated(translation.translatedText)
    });
  };

  const onChangeText = (text) => {
     setText(text);
     //handle translation when text change.
     newText(text);
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <ImageBackground
        source={require("./assets/book.png")}
        style={styles.backgroundImage}
      >
        <View style={styles.innerText}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>Welcome back Elisa, </Text>
          <Text>let's practice that pronunciation...</Text>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Word to translate"
            style={styles.input}
            onChangeText={onChangeText}
          />
        </View>

        <Text style={styles.output}>{translated}</Text>

        <View style={styles.button}>
          <Button
            title="START"
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("BACK_HOME")}
          />
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you! it actually works! but only on the browser..it wont work on the emulator.. giving me a crypto related error...

Comment: create a separate question if it's not directly related and we try to help from there.